# Why are security checks in the alternate universe more severe than the first one?

Tags: fringe

In the television series *Fringe*, why is it that the security checks -- both in roads and in high security areas such as headquarters -- are more severe, with all the Unique Ids and hand scanning, than in the original timeline / universe in which the series started?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They were more severe because after the kidnapping of Walternate's son, two paths emerged.  Walter on "our" side eventually ended up in an asylum and no one believed him about anything.  The Walternate Walter, instead, rose to power and knowing of the threat and being in a position of power within the government was able to drive huge levels of increased security based upon that threat from our universe.  It was Walternate's plan all along to rise to power based upon perceived threats and use that gained power to eventually launch attacks against our universe.

Comment: This answer is also supported by the fact in the alternate universe they explicitly say "after the kidnapping of the Bishop boy, all kidnappings are treated as Fringe incidents." I assume this also extends to all cases of infiltration or mistaken identity.